# how to bind a country flag span html element use it dynamically using flag-icon-css

Tags: css, angular

I have install the  flag-icon-css library in my app and i want to display the country flag based on the country bind variable set on my component. How can I achieve that?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-select-operator',
    templateUrl: './select-operator.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./select-operator.component.css']
})

export class SelectOperatorComponent implements OnInit {

    country: string = 'fr';
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

}
```

How can can I pass the value country to the my template.
my  select-operator.component.html template as below.

Can I replace fr with the field of country?

```
 <div>
    <div>Country: </div>
    <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-**fr**"></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Did you try the answer? Any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
<span class="flag-icon  flag-icon-{{ country }}"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<span [class]="'flag-icon  flag-icon-' +  country "></span>
```